# Using php Send command from webpage hosted on GoDaddy to run a .bat on a specif pc on a home network?

Tags: php

Morning,

I have a website hosted on Godaddy written with php.

I have a numebr of race servers hosted on a local pc at my home.

On the website I want to make it possible where members can chose a track and hit a button.

This button then sends a command from the webpage on GoDaddy to my local pc which runs a script to stop,rewrite,restart the server.

All parts of it are working except I am lost when it comes to getting the command from the webpage on the GoDaddy site to the locally hosted pc with the race servers on it.

Any info/help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use DynDns, ngrok, or something similar, to make your local machine reachable from the internet - and then trigger the functionality via a HTTP request?

Comment: And if you do that, make sure you know what you're doing in terms of security, because you're opening up a hole in your local network which could be exploited. Might be better (for security and performance and reliability) to host all this in the cloud?

Comment: You could make it event driven. You set up some message queue (like RabbitMQ or similar) and let both the godaddy site and your local server connect to it. Then your site on GoDaddy only need to add a message in the queue. Your local server will can then subscribe to that queue and consume the message and you can do what ever you need. That way your different servers will be decoupled from each other and you don't need to open the door to your home environment (which is always risky if you're not careful)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static (or pretty stable dynamic) IP-address *and* your router allows you to open ports, you can use the port forwarding feature in your browser to forward traffic from `<your external IP address>:<some port>` to `<IP of a device on your LAN>:<some port>`. Preferably, you only allow traffic on the external port from your GoDaddy hosted server (for example by using your router's built-in firewall).

Rather than outside-in, you can also go the other way. Your computer can actively:

- Poll for updates. Have your computer periodically ask the GoDaddy hosted server what to do. This is not the optimal way, but easy to set up. The device on your home network could, for example, request a page for instructions.
- Open a tunnel. If you have shell access to the server, you could create a SSH reverse tunnel or use a service like ngrok, Cloudflare Tunnel, etc.
- Set up a VPN between the two machines.